# What is the added value of the kestrel functional programming Design Pattern? (Scala)

Tags: scala, design-patterns, functional-programming

I'm wondering why is it so useful to put away the side effect part of a code using Kestrel. Does anyone has experience with it? and can explain the real motivation and how does it help exactly.

Although i understand that Pure functional programing is about zero-side effect and henceforth better debugging and predictability of the code. However in the case of Kestrel, I don't see how it really help to do that ?

Best,

MM-

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The point is to avoid creating an intermediate variable that you probably don't want to have lying around, or to avoid having to create a new block for something you're doing in passing.  Let's suppose we have the Kestrel as in Ruby:

```
implicit class RubyKestrel[A](val repr: A) extends AnyVal {
  def tap[B](f: A => B) = { f(repr); repr }
}
```

Now let's suppose we have some line of code:

```
xs.map(_ + 7).filter(foo).take(n)
```

and we want to print out a debugging message after the filter.  Without `tap` we refactor that line to:

```
{
  val temp = xs.map(_ + 7).filter(foo)
  println(temp)
  temp.take(n)
}
```

Ugh.  Now suppose we have `tap`:

```
xs.map(_ + 7).filter(foo).tap(println).take(n)
```

Whew, way better!

Let's suppose we have a stack that has an add method, and we want to add something to the stack before using it somewhere else.

```
def newStack = {
  val stack = new Stack
  stack add "whatever"
  stack
}
```

Ugh.  But with `tap`:

```
def newStack = (new Stack).tap(_ add "whatever")
```

Pretty handy--it really just lets you turn any normal side-effecting method into something that you can chain calls to.  And since chained calls are often lower boilerplate, that's often a big win.

Comment: That's also the need that naturally drove me to want a _tap_: I wanted to avoid having to creating variables and then repeat them at the end of the block. The code is shorter and more readable with _tap_ (to the point I think it should be part of Scala itself).