# View result of Scala Future for side effects

Tags: scala, future, side-effects

I have a method that returns a `Future`.  I want to log success or failure based on it, and then process the result.  In Java with streams, I would do something like

```
getCollection().stream().
  peek(e -> System.out.println("element: " + e).
  forEach(e -> doStuff(e))
```

Is there a similar way to "peek" at a Future?  I was hoping to write something like

```
getFuture().
  peek(checkResult).
  onComplete(processResult)

val checkResult: PartialFunction[Try[MyResult], Unit] = {
  case Success(s) => println("Success on " + s)
  case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
}
```

but the best that I can find is

```
getFuture().
  transform(checkResult).
  onComplete(processResult)

def checkResult(r: [Try[MyResult]) = r match {
  case Success(s) => {
    println("Success on " + s)
    r
  }
  case Failure(e) => {
    e.printStackTrace()
    r
  }
}
```

where I need to manually return the input.

Comment: couldn't you just .map(...) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there something like Java Stream's "peek" operation in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257367/is-there-something-like-java-streams-peek-operation-in-scala)

Comment: @sinanspd No, that is only called if the `Future` is successful. And it would still have to return the original value.

Comment: Well, technically you could wrap your error in an Either but I think the implicit solution provided in the link is better

Comment: @sinanspd No, the `map` method will only be called if the `Future` succeeds, so you won't get the stack trace that the OP wants if there is an error.

Answer (score 3):

`Future.andThen`:https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#andThen is for this purpose.

For your code, something like:

```
future.andThen(checkResult).onComplete(processResult)
```

This expression returns a new Future of what the original Future result before `andThen` operation. The operation passed in andThen is supposed to be side effects only and the result will be discarded. You can also chain a few `andThen`s together in a series to perform multiple side effects.