# 'tee' operation on Scala's option type?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Is there some sort of 'tee' operation on `Option` in Scala's standard library available? The best I could find is `foreach`, however its return type is `Unit`, therefore it cannot be chained.

This is what I am looking for: given an `Option` instance, perform some operation with side effects on its value if the option is not empty (`Some[A]`), otherwise do nothing; return the option in any case.

I have a custom implementation using an implicit class, but I am wondering whether there is a more common way to do this without implicit conversion:

```
object OptionExtensions {
  implicit class TeeableOption[A](value: Option[A]) {
    def tee(action: A => Unit): Option[A] = {
      value foreach action
      value
    }
  }
}
```

Example code:

```
import OptionExtensions._

val option: Option[Int] = Some(42)
option.tee(println).foreach(println) // will print 42 twice

val another: Option[Int] = None
another.tee(println).foreach(println) // does nothing
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't presume you'll see anything that implicitly injects side effects into a function in the standard library.

Comment: Side-effects and functional-programming are not friends.

Comment: There isn't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671620/how-to-keep-return-value-when-logging-in-scala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742060/equivalent-to-rubys-tap-method-in-scala

Comment: You can simply put your side-effecting operation into the normal map/flatmap methods.

Comment: I think your solution is the best way to do what you want to do. I don't think there's anything like that in the standard library.

Comment: No you can't, @puhlen.  If you call `option.map(println)` you end up with an `Option[Unit]` and he wants an `Option[Int]` still.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt `option.map{x => println(x); x}` prints x and gives you `Option[Int]`

Comment: It's simply not necessary, as you can define this as a function, like this: `def tee[A,B<:Iterable[A],U](b:B)(f:A=>U):B = {b foreach f; b}`  -- and then use it like this: `tee(option)(println)` -- But then again, why? That's what the semicolon is there for, is it not?

Comment: @puhlen I was thinking simpler but fair enough.

Comment: According to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231509/what-is-the-added-value-of-the-kestrel-functional-programming-design-pattern-s) it's called "kestrel" in ruby code. (Disclaimer: I don't know ruby.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid implicit conversion, instead of using method chaining you can use function composition with k-combinator.
k-combinator gives you an idiomatic way to communicate the fact that you are going to perform a side effect.

Here is a short example:

```
object KCombinator {
  def tap[A](a: A)(action: A => Any): A = {
    action(a)
    a
  }
}

import KCombinator._

val func = ((_: Option[Int]).getOrElse(0))
  .andThen(tap(_)(println))
  .andThen(_ + 3)
  .andThen(tap(_)(println))
```

If we call our func with an argument of `Option(3)` the result will be an Int with the value of `6`
and this is how the console will look like:

> 3
>
> 6

Comment: ... except that it doesn't work. :) Calling func(None) results in 0 and 3 being printed to stdout, which is not what is required. I accepted the answer nonetheless, since the idea was the right one and using `def tap[A](action: A => Any)(value: A): Option[A] = { action(value); Some(value) }` does the trick: `option.flatMap(tap(println)).foreach(println)` prints 42 twice if option is not empty; otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: It's printing 0 and 3 only because I called getOrElse(0). 
Returning Some(value) is wrong because you will end up with a nested Option of Option of... you get the idea which is not what you want.
I don't think it make a lot of sense to short circuit inside tap itself. You can pattern math inside the action of tap to get the exact same behaviour that you are looking for.

Comment: True, but I think it depends on the way the composition is done. In this sense I don't think that returning `Some(value)` is inherently *wrong*, only when using `andThen`.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an existing way to accomplish this in the standard library, because side effects are minimized and isolated in functional programming.  Depending on what your actual goals are, there are a couple different ways to idiomatically accomplish your task.

In the case of doing a lot of `println` commands, instead of sprinkling them throughout your algorithm, you would typically gather them in a collection, then do one `foreach println` at the end.  This minimizes the side effects to the smallest possible impact.  That goes with any other side effect.  Try to find a way to squeeze it into the smallest possible space.

If you are trying to chain a series of "actions," you should look into [futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).  Futures basically treat an action as a value, and provide a lot of useful functions to work with them.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use map, and make your side effecting functions conform to `action: A => A` rather than `action: A => Unit`.

```
 def tprintln[A](a: A): A = {
    println(a)
    a
 }
 another.map(tprintln).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Scala 2.13, we can use [scala.util.ChainingOps#tap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap%5BU%5D(f:A=%3EU):A).

Example:

```scala
import scala.util.chaining._

val result = Option(1)
  .tap(x => println(s"Input: $x"))
  .map(_ + 1)
  .tap(x => println(s"Output: $x"))
```

Result:

```
Input: Some(1)
Output: Some(2)
val result: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```